# List.js filter by radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to filter by radio button using List.js

The List.js is working fine, but I cannot figure out how to make it work by using radio buttons. Please assist.

Here is the fiddle:
[Jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nicholas116/3by1ena2/4/)

Here is the javascript part:

```
        var dap_list = new List('dap_list', {
      valueNames: ['waste_name', 'client_name', 'created_by', 'timestamp', 'dap_status'],
      page: 8,
      plugins: [
        ListPagination({})
      ]
    });

    $('#search_radio').change(function() {
      var selection = this.value;

      // filter items in the list
      dap_list.filter(function(item) {
        if (item.values().search_radio == selection) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      });

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made three small mistakes in your fiddle.

1. You forgot to include jQuery itself (click the "Javascript" button with the little gear on it)
2. Your radio buttons have he same ID. That's illegal in HTML. Remove the IDs, you don't need them.
3. You want to filter your items on `dap_status`, not on `search_radio`.

So, with this knowledge, we get:

```
$(':radio[name=search_radio]').change(function () {
    var selection = this.value;

    dap_list.filter(function (item) {
        return item.values().dap_status == selection;
    });
});
```

Note that

```
if (booleanCondition) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

is an anti-pattern. Don't do that, simply `return booleanCondition;` like I did above.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the duplicate IDs in your HTML.

```
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" class="search" name="search_radio" id="search_radio1" value="Awaiting Approval">Awaiting Approval
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" class="search" name="search_radio" id="search_radio2" value="Needs Further Review">Needs Further Review
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" class="search" name="search_radio" id="search_radio3" value="Approved">Approved
</label>
```

For the JS you can use:

```
    var dap_list = new List('dap_list', {
        valueNames: ['waste_name', 'client_name', 'created_by', 'timestamp', 'dap_status'],
        page: 8,
        plugins: [
            ListPagination({})
        ]
    });

    $('.search').change(function() {

        var selection = this.value;

        dap_list.filter(function(item) {
            var status = item.values().dap_status;
            return status == selection;
        });
    });
```